# How to find basis for subspace of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone please guide me with this,

I want to find a basis and its dimension for the subspace of 2x2 matrices such that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \\ \end{pmatrix} \bullet \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix} =0$$

I tried this;

I know I would get the linear system

$$a+2c=0$$

$$b+2d=0$$

$$2a+4c=0$$

$$2b+4d=0$$

which equivalent leaves the two equations $a+2c=0$ and $b+2d=0$

But I don't know how to proceed from this. Would I just factor our a,b,c,d from four matrices and those would be a basis? of dim 4? Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $a$ and $b$ determine $c$ and $d$, respectively - hence there are two free variables and the space has dimension $2$. Thus, once we find two linearly independent vectors in the space, they form a basis.

One example of that is to choose the matrix where $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, together with the matrix where $a = 0$ and $b = 1$. I'll leave it to you to check that they indeed are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for your time:  Is this what you are saying essentialy we could set c=s , d=t and write our solutions as s(-2,0,1,0)+t(0,-2,0,1) that is those two matrices would form basis?

Comment: Yes, assuming that by $(-2, 0, 1, 0)$ you mean a $2 \times 2$ matrix.